# Нет исключения при неверном регулярном выражении

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, c++builder

Во всех языках [(и в Си++)](http://ideone.com/EMkBOM) при создании неверной  регулярки бросается исключение. Но с билдеровским классом TRegEx этого почему-то не происходит. Как исправить?

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  TRegEx *reg;

  try
  {
    reg = new TRegEx("*.ts", (TRegExOptions)roIgnoreCase);
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    ShowMessage("catch");
  }
}
```

Comment: В смысле "как исправить"?

Comment: @Sublihim, в смысле, нужно получить исключение на неверный шаблон, либо как-то другим способом проверить корректность шаблона.

Comment: смотрите справку по *TRegEx*

Comment: @Sublihim, ничего интересного [не увидел](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На форуме разработчиков [Embarcadero](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=152480) предложен такой код:

```
function CheckRegEx(const Value: string): Boolean;
    var 
        myRegEx: TRegEx;
    begin
    try
        myRegEx := TRegEx.Create(Value, [roNotEmpty, roCompiled]);
        result := true;
    except
        result := false;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Кстати, по поводу скомпилированных выражений - они в памяти не остаются потом?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Не знаю. В [этом блоге](https://www.finalbuilder.com/resources/blogs/postid/413/getting-started-with-delphi-xes-regular-expressio) автор пишет, что никогда не освобождает объекты TRegEx, TMatch и TGroups, так как TRegEx - это Record с методами, а не классы, а значит утечки памяти быть не должно.

Comment: Я о другого рода утечке говорил. Когда регулярка компилируется, она может становиться непосредственно исполняемым кодом, который становится частью кодовой базы программы (а не её данных), а следовательно принципиально не может быть освобождён. Некоторые языки так делают, если не ошибаюсь.